# PDFBox on Mac critical error when silent printing

Tags: java, macos, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I have been experimenting with bumping my applications dependency on PDFBox to the 2.0.0 snapshot.
I'm having some major issues with it though...

So my code recieves a PDF as a BASE64 String, i decode it, and load the resulting bytearray into a PDDocument. Before I bumped the version number, calling `.silentPrint();`on the PDDocument worked like a charm.

The implementation of silent printing changed in 2.0.0, and I now do it this way:

```
private Status doPdfPrint(Document document, PrintService printService) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    PDDocument doc = null;
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    try {
        printerJob.setPrintService(printService);
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getDecodedData());

        doc = PDDocument.load(bais, true); //Force load

        PDFPrinter pdfPrinter = new PDFPrinter(doc);
        pdfPrinter.silentPrint(printerJob);

        doc.close();
        bais.close();
    } catch (IOException | PrinterException e) {
        log.warn("Failed to print! Exception occurred: {}", e.getMessage());
        log.debug("EXCEPTION", e);
        return Status.PRINTING_FAILED;
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bais);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(doc);
    }
    return Status.PRINTING_OK;
}
```

**However**, when running this on OSX Yosemite, this results in:

```
2015-02-12 08:10:44.475 java[20264:1353636] Cocoa AWT: Not running on AppKit thread 0 when expected. (
0   libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000125997782 +[ThreadUtilities getJNIEnv] + 38
1   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000012bf3004d syncFromJavaPixels + 1842
2   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000012bf304e3 LockImage + 75
3   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000012bf43040 Java_sun_java2d_CRenderer_doImage + 170
4   ???                                 0x0000000108c15694 0x0 + 4441855636
5   ???                                 0x0000000108c0798d 0x0 + 4441799053
)
2015-02-12 08:10:44.475 java[20264:1353636]     Please file a bug     report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2015-02-12 08:10:44.478 java[20264:1353636] java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.java2d.CRenderer.doImage(Native Method)
at sun.java2d.OSXSurfaceData.blitImage(OSXSurfaceData.java:1027)
at sun.java2d.CRenderer.blitImage(CRenderer.java:461)
at sun.java2d.CRenderer.scaleImage(CRenderer.java:455)
at sun.java2d.CRenderer.transformImage(CRenderer.java:508)
at sun.java2d.CRenderer.transformImage(CRenderer.java:582)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3461)
at sun.print.ProxyGraphics2D.drawImage(ProxyGraphics2D.java:1315)
at  org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawBufferedImage(PageDrawer.java:755)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:719)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:51)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:802)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:464)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:438)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:149)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:160)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPage(PDFRenderer.java:203)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(PDFRenderer.java:166)
at org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrinter$PDFPrintable.print(PDFPrinter.java:430)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob$4.run(CPrinterJob.java:653)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.printToPathGraphics(CPrinterJob.java:667)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.printLoop(Native Method)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.print(CPrinterJob.java:303)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1323)
at org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrinter.print(PDFPrinter.java:250)
at org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrinter.silentPrint(PDFPrinter.java:182)
at com.memnon.printr.PrintHandler.doPdfPrint(PrintHandler.java:123)
at com.memnon.printr.PrintHandler.print(PrintHandler.java:87)
at com.memnon.printr.PrintHandler.print(PrintHandler.java:77)
at com.memnon.printr.PrintHandler.print(PrintHandler.java:48)
at com.memnon.printr.communication.DocumentResponseHandler.handleSuccessful(DocumentResponseHandler.java:78)
at com.memnon.printr.communication.DocumentResponseHandler.handle(DocumentResponseHandler.java:53)
at com.memnon.printr.messaging.PrintConsumer.executePrinterJob(PrintConsumer.java:62)
at com.memnon.printr.messaging.PrintConsumer.run(PrintConsumer.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-02-12 08:10:44.493 java[20264:1353636] NSAlert is being used from a background thread, which is not safe.  This is probably going to crash sometimes. Break on void _NSAlertWarnUnsafeBackgroundThreadUsage() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
2015-02-12 08:10:46.639 java[20264:1353636] Apple AWT Internal Exception: Printing failed because PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog() returned -30871.
2015-02-12 08:10:46.639 java[20264:1353636] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Printing failed because PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog() returned -30871.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8895c66c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff890e876e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8895c51d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d117e80 -[NSPrintSpoolingGraphicsContext dealloc] + 43
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff890fb89c _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff890e1e8f _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 575
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88834302 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
7   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000012bf25fa4 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPrinterJob_printLoop + 165
8   ???                                 0x0000000108c15694 0x0 + 4441855636
9   ???                                 0x0000000108c07160 0x0 + 4441796960
10  ???                                 0x0000000108c0798d 0x0 + 4441799053
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea what's going on?
Regards

Comment: did you see the text "Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case" ?

Comment: It's quite intersting that both 1.8.8 and the current 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT call the same Java `Graphics2D.drawImage` method to draw an image, PDFBox merely tries to support more PDF features using e.g. equivalent `Graphics2D` rendering hints. Probably this improvement causes the *Cocoa AWT* `Graphics2D.drawImage` call to require *running on AppKit thread 0*.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes I did, and I plan to soon enough.

Comment: @mkl yes because some b/w images were poorly rendered.

Comment: @RobinJonsson if you can share the file, please do open a issue in PDFBOX JIRA. Although I doubt that it can be solved, it might still be useful to know about it. At least one of the committers (John Hewson, who also did the change that mkl mentioned) uses a mac.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Share the PDF file in question? Sure I can. 
@mkl Worth noting is that it worked perfectly printing silently in 1.8.8, i just tested. (Called `silentPrint()` directly on the `PDDocument`)
Regards

Comment: @TilmanHausherr this can be reproduced if the DPI isn't provided to `PDFPrintable` and using this file (likely reproducible with any PDF file as both we tried caused the crash):  https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/raw/2.0/assets/pdf_sample.pdf.  If the DPI is provided as non-zero (e.g. 300dpi), the crash does not seem to occur.

Comment: @QZSupport This is now a year old. Did you retest with 2.0 RC3? If yes and it still happens, as I said a year ago - open an issue in JIRA. I don't have a mac so I can't test it myself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I believe I opened a JIRA issue a year ago, and nothing happened. I can re-try with RC3 later this week and see if the issue is still there. I've been rolling 1.8.8 since i posted this

Comment: @QZSupport I'm sorry, I see you did: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2682

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Forgot to add to the JIRA case that silent printing worked form a non main-thread in 1.8.8. Basically what I'm saying in this SO post.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, FYI, the advice to file an upstream bug report is quite misleading.  I tried to do this and ran into several confusing roadblocks.  1. The MACOSX_PORT bug repository is read only.  2.  The upstream bug tracker (JBS) is exclusive to project maintainers 3. The submission process is a bit of a black box (type a bunch of text and hit send, hope for a response).  Perhaps a bit of a disclaimer would help.  As a PDFBOX user, it's hard to know how to help, and this seems to break on every PDF I've tried, making 2.0 much less appealing on Mac, regardless of who's bug it is. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm posting here 2 years after this occured for the first time..

It's still occuring. However, it's a Java bug, rather then a PDFBox bug. So after filing my bugreport on PDFBox issue-tracker, I got the advice to set a DPI for the document when doing printing. And voila it works. However, it's nearly impossible to figure out the DPI of a pdf document.

However, if you know what the DPI is, you can simply do this:

```
final int rasterizedDpi = 203;
final PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(data);
final PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
final PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(pdfDocument, Orientation.AUTO, false, rasterizedDpi);
job.setPageable(pageable);
job.print();
```

The hint here is the 4th argument to `PDFPageable`, the dpi...

Until Oracle fixes this JDK bug, i guess we're going to have to call this method :)

Comment: You should be able to fetch the DPI using `PrinterResolution.getDefaultAttributeValue(PrinterResolution.class);` however it always returns `null` on CUPS, so for non-Windows, you'd have to do something like a shell execute `lpoptions -p MY_PRINTER_NAME -l` and parse the output (after putting ENV `SOFTWARE=""` and `LANG=C` to force English locale).  Warning #2, Mac uses the `Description:` as the Java printer name versus the `.ppd`/CUPS printer name.  Warning #3, some LaserJets don't expose the DPI at all, so defaulting to 600 or 300 when it can't be detected is a good idea as well.

Comment: @QZSupport True, good ideas. However, when specifying a DPI, this causes the whole PDF to be rasterized, not only the inlined graphical elements of the PDF. This resulted in a very low quality printout :(

Comment: There are several factors which can impact quality, such as page size.  When you use a 4x6 PDF at 203 does it still suffer the same quality issues?  Reason I ask is 8.5 x 11 at 203 scaled to 4x6 is going to go through a 50% downsampling which is detrimental to the quality.   We ran into nearest neighbor scaling bugs with the Mac + Java graphics object.  Using a 4x6 PDF helps mitigate this.  Here's a 4x6 PDF you can try: https://github.com/qzind/tray/files/426462/barcode.pdf

Comment: This bug has been fixed with Java 8u131.