# Java Printing PDF File in Mac

Tags: java, macos, pdf, printing

I need to send a pdf file to the printer in Java with opening the default printing dialog where the user can select their preferences.

I'm using pdfbox to print it so far, but when printing PDFs with images under Mac OS, there is a bug the in the JDK:
[PDFBox on Mac critical error when silent printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471579/pdfbox-on-mac-critical-error-when-silent-printing). (There is a solution with rasterizes the document, but it is not very nice)

So I need to find a possibility to send the pdf file to the printer with opening this dialog. Is there any other free library with can do that? Or a terminal command (I tried `lpr` on the command line, but it never shows the dialog).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a partial answer. You can use Applescript to ask the Preview application to print the PDF file and show the print dialog:

```
tell application "Preview"
    print POSIX file "/Users/alan/CocoaFundamentals.pdf" with print dialog
end tell
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that it leaves the PDF document open in Preview.

The `osascript` program executes Applescripts from the terminal.